# Macbook Pro disconnecting from Wireless adapter (TP-LINK)

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, wireless-adapter

I'm using a wireless adapter (TP-Link TL-WPA281KIT AV200 With 1 LAN port 300M Wireless) to extend the connection form my SuperHub2 Router to the living room downstairs.

I had a previous router a few days ago, SuperHub 1, and I was having the same problem but the Mac was dropping off the connection only like once every 5 or 10 minutes.

Now, with the router update (sending signal y 2.5Ghz and 5Ghz bands) the Mac drops the connection every 10 seconds if I am not loading a video or loading new web sites constantly.

This issue seems to be directly related with [this other topic](https://superuser.com/questions/826338/macbook-air-constanty-drops-wifi-connection) but the solution proposed (pinging the router every 2 seconds) doesn't seem to be ideal...

It seems to me this is a problem with TP-LINK as it doesn't happen with the router wireless, but only with the TP-LINK adaptor.
Also, the related question I mention involves a TP-LINK router as well.

Any ideas about how to properly solve this annoying problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve it by accessing to the TP-LINK wireless adapter settings and changing the wireless mode to "n only" instead of "bgn mixed".

I came to this conclusion by reading [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15708128#15708128) and [this post](http://knowledgeexplosion.info/2010/11/resolved-request-timeout-for-icmp_seq-mac-os-x/)

In order to change the TP-Link wireless settings I had to go to their site and download the Powerline Utility (for Mac in my case). 
To do so I went to the [Download center](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download-center.html), looked for my model of wireless adapter and under the Utility tab I found the link to the application.

User and password by default is "admin".

[This link](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-398.html) also helped me.